# Installing viz plugins when deploying Superset via the Helm chart

Tags: plugins, dockerfile, kubernetes-helm, apache-superset

We are looking to get the following viz plugin installed [superset-indicator-chart](https://github.com/krsnik93/superset-indicator-chart), but I can't determine how to best install this when using the [Apache Helm chart](https://github.com/apache/superset/tree/master/helm/superset).

Existing documentation guides users to install the package under the directory `superset-frontend` using `npm`, then to edit a `MainPreset.js` file.

Ref: https://superset.apache.org/docs/contributing/creating-viz-plugins/

However, this is not possible when deploying via Helm. Is our only option to create a custom Dockerfile? What would this look like?

I've tried looking for existing code examples of this/documentation, but can't find anything relevant.